# Singular pronoun with plural reference in brackets

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

Which one is correct?

This:

> Everyone chose XYZ because it (and the ones from last year) **is** the most reliable.

or:

> Everyone chose XYZ because it (and the ones from last year) **are** the most reliable.

Comment: Parentheticals **need not** affect a sentence structure. Match grammatical number within the main structure (singular in this case). By the way, that's probably not a rule but merely a convention.

Comment: This question may have already been answered on these pages.

Comment: @Kris: that is true for most questions that are asked: they _may_ have been answered somewhere one these pages, and otherwise, chances are they _may_ have been answered on the internet, a written publication or a course. Without a reference to such an answer, that observation doesn't help the person looking for the answer, does it: ;)

Comment: You could change it to *"Everyone chose XYZ because it (as well as the ones from last year) is the most reliable"*, avoiding the question.

Comment: @oerkelens If a question has been answered on these pages, it's a dupe; it's easily found elsewhere, esp., on the Internet, then it's GR. Both cases are OT. See the FAQ.

Comment: @Kris - if it's a dupe, vote to close referring the original question.

Comment: @oerkelens An asker is expected to scan previous posts before asking. Just wait till the OP responds, *Patience!*

Comment: "*His jacket, not his shirt or his socks, always **seems** to match his slacks.* -- *jacket* is the subject. It is singular. The parenthetical expression does not affect the verb. *Her birthday celebration, together with the upcoming holiday, **makes** for a very full calendar.* -- *celebration* is the subject. The parenthetical expression does not affect the verb." (http://www.grammaruntied.com/blog/?p=225)

Comment: @Kris I did look for similar questions as per StackExchange etiquette. However my lingo is not up to scratch when it comes to languages, so I wasn't able to accurately phrase what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is correct.

> Everyone chose XYZ because it (and the ones from last year) is the
>   most reliable.

In the case of conflict between grammatical numbers in the sentence, the pronoun is matched according to the main sentence, and not the phrase inside the parenthesis.

***Note:** When you put something in parenthesis, the sentence should have complete meaning and correct grammar even if you completely remove the parenthesis.

Comment: What is the source of this information? Is it an opinion? I'm interested.

Comment: Multiple sources, sorry I can not recall them for you, but I've had this discussion multiple times. But there is one thing to consider that's even above this rule. When you put something in parenthesis, the sentence should have complete meaning and correct grammar even if you completely remove the parenthesis.

Comment: What is the source of the 'one thing to consider'? Is that an opinion?

Comment: The source is from 2 of my high-school English teachers in Hillhead High-school, Glasgow, United Kingdom

Comment: These are pretty basic grammar rules in the English language and questions regarding this matter is better asked in another community. Please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com/ for further information.

Comment: It's arguable that this particular use of parenthesis needs replacing by a rewrite.