Is "The fruit (4 pears and 3 apples)" singular or plural?
Which is correct please?

The fruit (4 pears and 3 apples) are on the table.

OR

The fruit (4 pears and 3 apples) is on the table.


Almost the same as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178381/singular-pronoun-with-plural-reference-in-brackets

Does this answer your question? Do parenthetical statements change subject-verb agreement? The answer is no, whether the parenthetical is additive ('together with the bread / together with the vegetables') or, as here, appositive (here, an expansive paraphrase).

"The fruit (considered as a type of food) is on the table."
"The fruits (considered as individual pieces of fruit) are on the table."

Also "the pieces of fruit are …“
